# How to shuffle ndarray/pandas dataframe rows within selected columns indices preserving other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I have an array:

```py
a = np.array([[1,3,9,8,4],
              [2,4,6,1,9],
              [7,3,0,5,8],
              [1,6,9,2,4]])
```

I want to randomly select 3 columns and randomly shuffle the elements across those columns (preserving them in the same row).

E.g. if the `column_indices = [0,2,3]` the new array will be:

```
a = np.array([[8,3,1,9,4],
              [1,4,6,2,9],
              [0,3,5,7,8],
              [1,6,2,9,4]])
```

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible constructor for your array

Comment: Also a discrepancy: you randomly select 2 columns but then mention 3 indices.

Comment: I mean to provide valid code. `a = np.array([...])` and to ensure this produces the correct array

Comment: Edited the question to have all the data with no duplication. Please, make sure you put the minimum info that is easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete code to use:

```py
column_indices = [0,2,3]

a = np.array([[1,3,9,8,4],
              [2,4,6,1,9],
              [7,3,0,5,8],
              [1,6,9,2,4]])

# transpose to switch from columns to rows
shuffled = a[:, column_indices].transpose()
np.random.shuffle(shuffled)

a[:, column_indices] = shuffled.transpose()
a
```

Comment: This randomize between the rows, I want to randomize between the columns (e.g. switch the value of columns 0,2,3 for the same row)

Comment: See it updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) on the slice (`shuffle` acts on the **first axis**, which is what you want):

```
# shuffle in place
np.random.shuffle(a[:, [0,2,3]])

# see changes
print(a)
```

output:

```
[[1 3 9 8 4]
 [2 4 6 1 9]
 [7 3 0 5 8]
 [1 6 9 2 4]]
```

Comment: Can it be done not inplace?

Comment: No, but you can first make a copy: `b = a.copy() ; np.random.shuffle(b[:, [0,2,3]])`

Comment: this method doesnt change the array when I try it:
a = np.array([[8,3,1,9,4],
              [1,4,6,2,9],
              [0,3,5,7,8],
              [1,6,2,9,4]])

np.random.shuffle(a[:, [1,2,3]])
print(a)

And I get the same array:
[[8 3 1 9 4]
 [1 4 6 2 9]
 [0 3 5 7 8]
 [1 6 2 9 4]]

Comment: See the code sample below. You shall paste the shuffled array on the initial indices.